# How should I have outpout from errors in PHPUNIT with Gitlab CI

Tags: laravel, gitlab, phpunit, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to run phpunit from Gitlab CI.

In local, I can run it, and I will have the error displaying when a test fails.

But in Gitlab CI, I have:

```
$ ./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --verbose
PHPUnit 9.5.3 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Runtime:       PHP 8.0.3
Configuration: /builds/project-0/phpunit.xml

..EESSEEEEEEEEEEEEEEESSSSSSSSSSSESSSSSSEEEESSSSSEEEEEEESSSSSEEE  63 / 190 ( 33%)
E.Etesting that url:/nova-api/individual-reports has responde code:200
Etesting that url:/nova-api/individual-reports has responde code:200
Etesting that url:/nova-api/individual-reports has responde code:200
EEtesting that url:/nova-api/individual-reports has responde code:200
Etesting that url:/nova-api/individual-reports has responde code:200
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEESEEEEEEEEEERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
FATAL: exit code 1
```

Here is my .gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: php:8.0

cache:
  paths:
    - vendor/

variables:
  APP_ENV: "local"
  APP_NAME: "APP_NAME"
  DB_CONNECTION: "sqlite"

before_script:
  # Install git, the php image doesn't have installed
  - apt-get update -yqq
  - apt-get install git libmagickwand-dev  libzip-dev -yqq

  # Install Xdebug & imagick
  - pecl install xdebug
  - git clone https://github.com/Imagick/imagick
  - cd imagick && phpize
  - ./configure
  - make
  - make install
  - cd ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}  # Change it to variable
  - cp .env.example .env
  - docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg
  - docker-php-ext-enable xdebug imagick
  - docker-php-ext-install pcntl exif gd zip

  # Install composer
  - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php

  # Install all project dependencies

  - php composer.phar config http-basic.nova.laravel.com ${NOVA_USERNAME} ${NOVA_PASSWORD} && php composer.phar install
  - php artisan key:generate
  - touch ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/database/database.sqlite
  - php artisan migrate --database=sqlite



# Run our tests
test:
  script:
    - ./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --verbose
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./storage/logs # for debugging
    expire_in: 7 days
    when: always
```

How should I see the details of my errors ?

Answer (score 0):

I ran phpunit with --testdox:

```
- ./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --testdox
```

Now, I have the details about the success or error in a test:

```
✔ Component can be retrieved with correct resource elements
 ✘ Operation is required on create
   │
   │ Expected status code 500 but received 419.
   │ Failed asserting that 500 is identical to 419.
   │
   │ /builds/project-0/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Testing/TestResponse.php:187
   │ /builds/project-0/tests/Feature/UserInvoiceData/UserInvoiceDataResourceTest.php:154
```